# How to add if else condition to data in Realtime Database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am working on a Flutter project, which is a tricycle booking system. Right now, I want to implement the functionality of having life points for every account. I have thought of this for some time and I have decided to store a value in the real-time database in firebase, it is where I will be decrementing the life points every time a user cancels the booking. What I want to do right now, is to check if the value stored in lifePoints is equal to a certain value, if yes, then I will be placing some functions and restrictions in there. So, how do i get the data from realtime database using flutter and add conditions to it?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read data from Firebase, the documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_data) is a great starting point.

From there comes this great example of reading data once:

```
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
final snapshot = await ref.child('users/$userId').get();
if (snapshot.exists) {
    print(snapshot.value);
} else {
    print('No data available.');
}
```

And this example for listening for data, which provides both the current value right away, and then continues to listen for updates:

```
DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('posts/$postId/starCount');
starCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    final data = event.snapshot.value;
    updateStarCount(data);
});
```

If you want to increment/decrement a value in the database, have a look at this example from the documentation on [atomic increments/decrements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments):

```
void addStar(uid, key) async {
  Map<String, Object?> updates = {};
  updates["posts/$key/stars/$uid"] = true;
  updates["posts/$key/starCount"] = ServerValue.increment(1);
  updates["user-posts/$key/stars/$uid"] = true;
  updates["user-posts/$key/starCount"] = ServerValue.increment(1);
  return FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().update(updates);
}
```

Or if you want to perform a more complex update of a value based on its current value, you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions):

```
DatabaseReference postRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("posts/foo-bar-123");

TransactionResult result = await postRef.runTransaction((Object? post) {
  // Ensure a post at the ref exists.
  if (post == null) {
    return Transaction.abort();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _post = Map<String, dynamic>.from(post as Map);
  if (_post["stars"] is Map && _post["stars"][uid] != null) {
    _post["starCount"] = (_post["starCount"] ?? 1) - 1;
    _post["stars"][uid] = null;
  } else {
    _post["starCount"] = (_post["starCount"] ?? 0) + 1;
    if (!_post.containsKey("stars")) {
      _post["stars"] = {};
    }
    _post["stars"][uid] = true;
  }

  // Return the new data.
  return Transaction.success(_post);
});
```

As you might notice these are all code snippets from the documentation, all from the same page even. I recommend spending some time studying that documentation, and then trying to apply these to your own use-case. If you then run into problems while implementing the use-case, post a question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can probably help further.